# C# How do you add text prior to the last slash in a string?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to keep the entire string, but add text prior to the last slash in a string.

Current error:

Syntax error, ',' expected

```
string test = @"C:\Windows\Temp\Test1";
string strTarget = test.Insert(test.LastIndexOf "\", "\\addedtext1\addedtext2\\");
```

Where is the syntax incorrect please and should this get the me the desired result? If not, what other things should I try please?

Example:

> C:\Windows\Temp\Test1

Desired Result:

> C:\Windows\Temp\addedtext1\addedtext2\Test1

Comment: Along with the problem you should **include the code you have up until this point** (*make some effort to answer your problem/question as [so] is not a code writing service*). After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Writing the Perfect Question*](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: I have learned more and modified the question to meet guidelines.  I had open another question which was different and added the error I was getting.  So, it's my understanding I'm supposed to modify this question, which I did and then try to reopen it to meet the guidelines.  Although the other question has answers, please let me know if this is incorrect.  Thanks for the help.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67891662/c-sharp-how-to-add-text-in-a-string-before-the-very-last-slash

Comment: Why you posted duplicates? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67891662/c-sharp-how-to-add-text-in-a-string-before-the-very-last-slash  Do i need to add that answer here too?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, This was the original question and I deleted it, changed the question and then I was corrected on how to do things.  I was guided to fix this original question, rather than repost a new one (the one you answered.)  If you don't mind posting your answer here, yes please. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the right tool for the job which is the [`System.IO.Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=net-5.0) class:

```
string test = @"C:\Windows\Temp\Test1";
string file = Path.GetFileName(test);
string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(test);
string result = Path.Combine(dir, "addedtext1", "addedtext2", file);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, don't forget the parentheses around the function arguments.

After allowing for that, `test.LastIndexOf("\")` is not complete, because the backslash is escaping the end quote. You need either `test.LastIndexOf("\\")` or `test.LastIndexOf(@"\")`.

This string literal also includes an unescaped backslash: `"\\addedtext1\addedtext2\\"`

Finally, you should look at the `System.IO.Path` API for this:

```
string test = @"C:\Windows\Temp\Test1";
string toAppend = @"\addedtext1\addedtext2\";

string basePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(test);
string fileName = Path.GetFileFileName(test);
string result =   Path.Combine(basePath, toAppend, fileName);
```

Just use caution if you run this on a server platform different than the source of the strings, where certain root or separator attributes are different.

Answer (score 0):

Dont play with string rather than use `DirectoryInfo` and `Path.Combine`. Using DirectoryInfo you can check if folder exist and other validations as well. Path.Combine is always better approach if you have need to play with paths.

**you can implement like this**

```
string direcctoryPath = @"C:\Windows\Temp\Test1";
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(direcctoryPath);
string targetPath = Path.Combine(directoryInfo.Parent.FullName, "addedtext1", "addedtext2", directoryInfo.Name);
```

--> output : C:\Windows\Temp\addedtext1\addedtext2\Test1